# Access logged in user from extra template tags file

Tags: python, django

I try to create a django template tag in which I need the logged in user, e.g. 

`@register.filter()
def foo(id):
    return Bar.objects.get(creator = request.user.id)`

but I get a NameError, saying that request is not defined. Is there a way to access the request object in app_extras file?

Comment: That seems an odd use for a filter. Are you sure you don't want a tag?

Comment: And anyway you don't need either here, really, since you can just do `request.user.bar_set.all` in the template. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple_tag instead of a filter, which accepts a "takes_context" parameter.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def foo(context):
    user = context['request'].user
    return Bar.objects.get(creator=user)
```

Keep in mind that "context" must be the first parameter.